# not able to select an entire block in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I created a group and number of subscriber is displaying under the group
I am trying to get the entire block. i.e. group name under the group name number of subscriber so once i am creating a group again its locator value is getting changed. I tried to dfind the block by usibng:

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\li[contains(text(), 'select4027')]")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

Its selecting the default group name. How do i select that block i.e my created group along with its no. of subscribers.

Comment: Please add the relevant `html` to the question

Comment: <li id="select4050" class="listOneItem" data-group="" data-school="4050">

Comment: <div class="listChecked">

Comment: Not just one line, all the relevant html. The html  you posted has nothing to do with the `xpath` you are using.

Comment: ul class="groupUl">
<li id="select3912" class="listOneItem" data-group="" data-school="3912">
<li id="select3911" class="listOneItem" data-group="" data-school="3911">
<li id="select4092" class="listOneItem" data-group="" data-school="4092">
<div class="listChecked">
<input id="class1" class="selectList" type="checkbox">
<label class="labelForCheckbox groupSelectClick" for="selectList">
<span class="iconCheck"></span>
<span class="grpName">Group1</span>

Comment: if this is the html <div class="msgsCount" title="5000">
<div class="msgHeadMobile" title="Sent To">Sent</div> then how i will locate the complete block